# nested include is not showing data for second include

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to get 2 left outer join from sequelize by using nested include. But, second include inside 1st include is not returning table's data.

```
call.hasMany(session,{
    as: "sessions"
})
session.belongsTo(call,{
    foreignKey: "call_id",
    as: "call"  
})
session.hasMany(session_extra_data,{
    as: "sessionExtraData"
})
session_extra_data.belongsTo(session,{
    foreignKey: "session_id",
    as: "session"
})
call.findAll({
    limit: 5,   
    include: [{
        model: session,
        as: "sessions",
        indlude:[{
            model: session_extra_data,
            as: "sessionExtraData",
        }],
        required: false
    }],
}).then(data => {
    console.log("DATA", JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

call model

```
const call = sequelize.define('call', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true, 
        field: 'id'
    },
    version: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        field: 'version'
    },
    
    
},{
    freezeTableName:true,
    timestamps: false
});
```

Session model

```
const session = sequelize.define('session', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true, 
        field: 'id'
    },
    version: {
        field: 'version',
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    callId : {
        field: 'call_id',
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false
    },
},{
    freezeTableName:true,
    timestamps: false
});
```

session extra model

```
const session_extra_data = sequelize.define('session_extra_data', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true, 
        field: 'id'
    },
    version: {
        field: 'version',
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    tenantId: {
        field: 'tenant_id',
        type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    sessionId : {
        field: 'session_id',
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false
    },
},{
    freezeTableName:true,
    timestamps: false
});
```

I have put all the model definition in code.
you can see and tell me what i am doing wrong.

there is foreign key in session table data of call id as call_id
there is foreign key in session-extra-data table data of Session id as session_id

Comment: could you include the `sequelize` model definitions for the `call`, `session`, and `session_extra_data` models?  You have a lot of aliases with the `as` property, and it's difficult to tell what might be happening without the `sequelize.define(...)` or 'call.init(...)` definitions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because there are some missing properties being defined on the associations.  As a result, there are probably multiple columns in the database that are being used as foreign keys.  Try this instead:

```
call.hasMany(session,{
    as: "sessions",
    foreignKey: "call_id",
    sourceKey: "id"
})
session.belongsTo(call,{
    foreignKey: "call_id",
    targetKey: "id",
    as: "call"  
})
session.hasMany(session_extra_data,{
    as: "sessionExtraData",
    foreignKey: "session_id",
    sourceKey: "id"
})
session_extra_data.belongsTo(session,{
    foreignKey: "session_id",
    targetKey: "id",
    as: "session"
})
call.findAll({
    limit: 5,   
    include: [{
        model: session,
        as: "sessions",
        indlude:[{
            model: session_extra_data,
            as: "sessionExtraData",
        }],
        required: false
    }],
}).then(data => {
    console.log("DATA", JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

You might also want to check your database schema to make sure that there aren't any extra foreign key columns in the `sessions` and `session_extra_data` tables....  This might happen if

```
await sequelize.sync()
```

was being executed at some point in the code.

*Edit*  On the model definitions for `sequelize`, try the following for the foreign keys:

```
const session = sequelize.define('session', {
    // ...
    callId : {
        field: 'call_id',
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: call,
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
    // ...
}, {
    freezeTableName:true,
    timestamps: false
})

// ...

const session_extra_data = sequelize.define('session_extra_data', {
    // ...
    sessionId : {
        field: 'session_id',
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: session,
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
    // ...
}, {
    freezeTableName:true,
    timestamps: false
})
```

Comment: i tried the way you but still didn't work. and there is not extra foreign key in sessions except "call_id" and in session_extra_data except "session_id"

Comment: i have put the model definitions please check

Comment: @Tayyab I added a suggestion about the model definitions to my answer.  Also, were you able to check the database to see if you might happen to have any extra columns in the `session` and `session_extra_data` tables?

Comment: Great, Thanks mate. You save my day. It works. Thanks a lot @Andrew :) :)